# Нужны ли кавычки для антиоксидантов?

Tags: пунктуация

"Что такое антиоксиданты, и какова их роль в нашем организме" — название статьи.
Почему-то цитата «что такое "хорошо" и что такое "плохо"» не вызывает сомнений о постановке кавычек. Здесь же у меня дилемма.